# MySQL: dividir string [SP]

Tags: mysql, string, stored-procedure

El procedimiento recibe dos parámetros: el string y el separador. Si no se encuentra el separador, o el string es `null` o el separador es `null`, devuelve el string sin procesar. Si se encuentra el separador, crea una tabla temporal con una cantidad de campos igual a la cantidad de separadores encontrados en el string. Luego inserta los substrings en la tabla y con un `select` devuelve el `resultset`.

Procedimiento:

```
/**
Este procedimiento divide un string por separador

@param [string] cadena a dividir
@param [char] separador
@return [mixed] 

Si la cadena str o el separador son nulos o están vacíos, devuelve la cadena str.
Si se encuentra el separador, devuelve un resultset con la cadena str separada por separador.

En esta versión, se utiliza una tabla temporal. En la anterior se crean variables dinámicas y en la siguiente devolverá un string con formato JSON
*/    
    drop procedure if exists dividir_string_tmp;
    delimiter //
    create procedure dividir_string_tmp(in str longtext, in separador varchar(5))
    bloque: begin
        declare cant_sep int; /* cantidad de separadores encontrados en str */
        declare contador int; 
        declare consulta_tbl_tmp longtext; /* consulta resultante para crear la tabla temporal */
        declare consulta_update longtext; /* consulta resultante para añadir los datos a la tabla temporal */
        declare consulta_resultset longtext; /* consulta resultante para devolver el resultset */
        declare str_parcial longtext; /* porción de str */
        declare nombre_campo varchar(10); /* contiene el nombre de los campos de la tabla temporal */
        
        
        if ((str is null) or (str = "")) or ((separador is null) or (separador = "")) then
            select str;
            leave bloque;
        end if;
        
        /* buscar la cantidad de separadores */
        set cant_sep = (select round((length(str) - length(replace(str, separador, ""))) / length(separador)));
        
        if (cant_sep = 0) then /* no se encontró el separador, devolver el str*/
            select str;
            leave bloque;
        else
            set contador = 1;
            set nombre_campo = "str";
            set consulta_tbl_tmp = "create temporary table tmp_dividir_string (";
            set consulta_update = "insert into tmp_dividir_string values (";
            set consulta_resultset = "select * from tmp_dividir_string";
            
            drop table if exists tmp_dividir_string;
            
            while (contador <= (cant_sep+1)) do
                
                set str_parcial = trim(substring_index(substring_index(str, separador, contador), separador, -1));
                set consulta_tbl_tmp = concat(consulta_tbl_tmp, nombre_campo, contador, " longtext");
                set consulta_update = concat(consulta_update, "'", str_parcial, "'");
    
                if (contador <= cant_sep) then
                    set consulta_tbl_tmp = concat(consulta_tbl_tmp, ", ");
                    set consulta_update = concat(consulta_update, ", ");
                end if;
                set contador = contador + 1;
            end while;
            set consulta_tbl_tmp = concat(consulta_tbl_tmp, ")");
            set consulta_update = concat(consulta_update, ")");
    
        end if;
    /*   útil  para ver las consultas resultantes
        select (consulta_tbl_tmp) as resultado;
        select (consulta_update) as resultado;
    */
    
        /* crear la tabla */
        set @sql = consulta_tbl_tmp; 
        prepare stmt from @sql; 
        execute stmt; 
        deallocate prepare stmt;
        
        /* actualizar la tabla */
        set @sql = consulta_update; 
        prepare stmt from @sql; 
        execute stmt; 
        deallocate prepare stmt;
        
        /* mostrar el resultado */
        set @sql = consulta_resultset; 
        prepare stmt from @sql; 
        execute stmt; 
        deallocate prepare stmt;
    
    end //
    
    delimiter ;
```

Modo de uso:

```
set @dato_tmp = "dato1, dato2, dato3, , dato5, dato6, dato7, dato8, dato9, dato10, , dato11, ";
set @separador_tmp = ",";
call dividir_string_tmp(@dato_tmp, @separador_tmp);
```

Cualquier sugerencia para mejorarla es bienvenida. Saludos!

Comment: Esta no es la forma de colaborar. El formato de [es.so] es el siguiente: 1 pregunta bien hecha en el área de preguntas y una o más respuestas en el área de respuestas. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour] para que entiendas cómo funciona el sitio. Gracias por el aporte, pero por favor, usa el formato correcto del sitio. Saludos

Comment: Bueno, voy a eliminar la primer oración y dejar el resto, que la solicitud de sugerencia para mejorarla ahí está.

Comment: ¿Qué sería mejorar? ¿Menos código, mas desempeño, legibilidad o mantenibilidad, ...?

Comment: Buena pregunta. En cuanto a mantenimiento, no creo que requiera mucho. En cuanto a legibilidad creo que es aceptable. En cuanto a menos código, sé que por ejemplo podría poner un "inline" `declare`, lo mismo con los `set` pero no sacrificaría legibilidad? Y en cuanto a desempeño: si. creo que seguramente se pueda mejorar. Y estoy viendo que podría poner un parámetro adicional para el prefijo del nombre del campo y tal vez que el primer campo de la tabla sea la cantidad de substrings para facilitar el tratamiento del resultset.

Comment: @Sal no me salía arrobarte